# Deleting a specific word from a file in python

Tags: python, text-files

I am quite new to python and have just started importing text files. I have a text file which contains a list of words, I want to be able to enter a word and this word to be deleted from the text file. Can anyone explain how I can do this?

```
text_file=open('FILE.txt', 'r')
ListText = text_file.read().split(',')
DeletedWord=input('Enter the word you would like to delete:')
NewList=(ListText.remove(DeletedWord))
```

I have this so far which takes the file and imports it into a list, I can then delete a word from the new list but want to delete the word also from the text file.

Comment: Usually questions go better if you post what you've tried and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Well I was more wondering if there was a general function such as 'del' or something which would always work?

Comment: Nope, there is not. Python includes a lot of things but it still expects you to write some code.

Comment: If you're not opposed to using shell commmands I'm sure its possible somehow, but @DavidZ is right, there's no direct way to do it in Python

Comment: @user3130576, please post large code blocks in your question formatted as code blocks (there should be a "{}" button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would recommend since its fairly simple and I don't think you're concerned with performance.:

```
f = open("file.txt",'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

excludedWord = "whatever you want to get rid of"

newLines = []
for line in lines:
    newLines.append(' '.join([word for word in line.split() if word != excludedWord]))

f = open("file.txt", 'w')
for line in lines:
    f.write("{}\n".format(line))
f.close()
```

This allows for a line to have multiple words on it, but it will work just as well if there is only one word per line

**In response to the updated question:**

You cannot directly edit the file (or at least I dont know how), but must instead get all the contents in Python, edit them, and then re-write the file with the altered contents

Another thing to note, `lst.remove(item)` will throw out the first instance of `item` in `lst`, and only the first one.  So the second instance of `item` will be safe from `.remove()`.  This is why my solution uses a list comprehension to exclude all instances of `excludedWord` from the list.  If you really want to use `.remove()` you can do something like this:

```
while excludedWord in lst:
    lst.remove(excludedWord)
```

But I would discourage this in favor for the equivalent list comprehension

Comment: I have used what you have suggested and it works, thank you, and sorry about the initial lack of clarity in my question.

Comment: @user3130576, not a problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

We can replace strings in files (some imports needed;)):

```
import os
import sys
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=1):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('old_string', 'new_string'))
```

Find this (maybe) here: http://effbot.org/librarybook/fileinput.htm

If 'new_string' change to '', then this would be the same as to delete 'old_string'.

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying something similar, here are some points to people whom might end up reading this thread. The only way you can replace the modified contents is by opening the same file in "w" mode. Then python just overwrites the existing file.
I tried this using "re" and sub():

```
import re
f = open("inputfile.txt", "rt")
inputfilecontents = f.read()
newline = re.sub("trial","",inputfilecontents)
f = open("inputfile.txt","w")
f.write(newline)
```

Comment: If we do not like "re" we can also use this instead: newline = inputfilecontents.replace("trial","")

Answer (score 0):

@Wnnmaw your code is a little bit wrong there it should go like this

```
f = open("file.txt",'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

excludedWord = "whatever you want to get rid of"

newLines = []
for line in newLines:
    newLines.append(' '.join([word for word in line.split() if word != excludedWord]))

f = open("file.txt", 'w')
for line in lines:
    f.write("{}\n".format(line))
f.close()
```

Comment: This should be a comment on the other answer, not a separate answer.