# AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, file-io

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
print "starting to read \n"

fw=open('cde.txt','w');

with open('test.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
                fw.write('\n')
                fw.write(line)
fp.close()
fw.close()

print "\ndone with writing \n"

print "starting to print from another file \n"

with open('cde.txt','r+') as ss:
    for line in ss:
        for word in line.split():
                if word in stopwords.words('english'):
                        #ss.write(line.remove(word))
                        ss.remove(word)

 #print line.rstrip()
ss.close()

#for word in line.split():

print "done with printing from another file"
```

I am running this script but keep getting

```
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

error.

Comment: What you actually want to achieve?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005921/deleting-a-specific-word-from-a-file-in-python)

Comment: i wanted to remove stopwords from a file

Comment: @saicharankandibanda What's actually your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since the exact trace of the error is missing from the question, I'd guess the failure is due to the call to `ss.remove()`. From this code `ss` seems to be a file handle, and (as the error suggests) file objects don't support `remove()` method.

If you want to remove the file, you may use `os.remove(filepath)`, but this code does not seem to be doing that. Right now the code is trying to remove the word from the file (which is not a supported operation like this).

If you'd like to remove words from your file, a simple approach would be to start creating another file (like a temporary one) that contains only the desired information, and after processing is finished, replace the old file with this new generated file (and possibly remove the temporary file at the end).

If you'd like to exclude `stopwords` from the data, you may keep the data in a list, like this:

```
with open('cde.txt.cleared', 'w+') as output:
    with open('cde.ext', 'r+') as ss:
        for line in ss:
            words = line.strip().split()
            for word in words:
                if word in stopwords.words('english'):
                    words.remove(word)
            output.write(' '.join(words) + '\n')
```

Note that we opened the output file in write mode.
Also note that this code does not preserve the number of spaces between words since it converts the line to a list, and then constructs the line again from those words. If that's an issue, I think you might need to work on the strings rather than splitting them to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing OP wants to remove stopwords from the file. To do this, try:

```
for line in ss:
    parts = line.split()
    for word in xrange(len(parts)):
        if parts[word] in in stopwords.words('english'):
            parts.remove(parts[word])

    ss.write(' '.join(parts))
```

I do hope this sorts you. If it doesn't, do leave a comment with more detail.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i added the following code and ran the script again

with open('cde.txt','r+') as ss:
   for line in ss:
        for word in xrange(len(line.split())):
                if line[word] in stopwords.words('english'):
                        line.remove(word)
ss.write(line)

but i get the following error now

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 21, in <module>
    line.remove(word)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: Sorry, matey, a bit of sloppy coding on my part, it should be fine now

Comment: heyy,

now i am getting this error..

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 22, in <module>
    parts.remove(word)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: @saicharankandibanda try now?

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is reading text from test.txt file and writing the same text to 'cde.txt' file after removing the stopwords.
This might help you.

```
linetext=[]
for line in ss:
    line1=[]
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in stopwords.words('english'):
            line1.append(word)

    linetext.append(" ".join(line1))
    linetext.append('\n')
with open('cde.txt','wb') as fw:
    fw.writelines(linetext)
```